# Are there presently any countries seeing high inflation whose central banks did not greatly expand the money supply during the pandemic?

Tags: inflation

Often the recent spike in inflation is attributed to kinks in supply chains. My question is basically are there countries with high inflation where we can rule out that it is primarily caused by monetary and fiscal policy of their governments and central banks.  Let's say "high" means more than triple the annual rate before the pandemic.

Comment: What’s your definition of high inflation? Above 2% pa, 5% pa 10%, pa 20% pa x% pa?

Comment: @1muflon1 thanks I edited and chose an arbitrary criterion of 3x the previous rate .  idk how reasonable thAt is tho

Comment: well it’s not just about reasonableness but rather to factually answer your question there needs to be some boundary - high inflation is not economic term it can mean anything between 0 and infinity inflation. Also by average inflation pre-pandemic you mean average of a year before a pandemic or whole history of a country before pandemic?

Comment: @Timkinsella In [the Euro area the inflation rate for 2020 was 0.25%](https://www.statista.com/statistics/267908/inflation-rate-in-eu-and-euro-area/), so under this rule 1% would qualify as high inflation (:

Comment: @Giskard lol darn ok I will have to think of a better criterion

Comment: @1muflon1 yeah i meant 2019